# Issue using PrimeNG

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm kinda new to programming itself and I am currently trying to build a Web-Overlay Demo with PrimeNG, but I'm running into issues.
I used the "Demo" Code from primefaces.org to display a PanelMenu, but it is not showing up. I've tried Buttons and Accordeon first and it worked.

Here's my Code:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {PanelMenu,MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';


@Component({
    selector: 'menu',
    template: `<p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{'width':'300px'}"></p-panelMenu>`,
    directives: [PanelMenu],
})


export class PanelMenuDemo implements OnInit {
  
    private items: MenuItem[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [
            {
                label: 'File',
                icon: 'fa-file-o',
                items: [{
                        label: 'New', 
                        icon: 'fa-plus',
                        items: [
                            {label: 'Project'},
                            {label: 'Other'},
                        ]
                    },
                    {label: 'Open'},
                    {label: 'Quit'}
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'Edit',
                icon: 'fa-edit',
                items: [
                    {label: 'Undo', icon: 'fa-mail-forward'},
                    {label: 'Redo', icon: 'fa-mail-reply'}
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'Help',
                icon: 'fa-question',
                items: [
                    {
                        label: 'Contents'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Search', 
                        icon: 'fa-search', 
                        items: [
                            {
                                label: 'Text', 
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        label: 'Workspace'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'File'
                            }
                    ]}
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'Actions',
                icon: 'fa-gear',
                items: [
                    {
                        label: 'Edit',
                        icon: 'fa-refresh',
                        items: [
                            {label: 'Save', icon: 'fa-save'},
                            {label: 'Update', icon: 'fa-save'},
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Other',
                        icon: 'fa-phone',
                        items: [
                            {label: 'Delete', icon: 'fa-minus'}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

I'm referring to the selector within my html body. I've got all the css and js stuff injected via gulp.inject and as already said, Buttons and Accordeon just works fine.

Please don't forget that I am really new to programming, so be patient and talk to me as if I'm stupid! ;)
Thanks so far!

EDIT:

I've added a plunkr for this.
This time I've tried to use a simple "Menu" from PrimeNG.
I'm getting the error "no router provider", but I'm not using ANY routers at all.
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2bIuKmyTSYuwPyn0muZF)

```
My folder structur is like this: 
config
--config.js
dist
--distfiles
src
--app.component.html/.scss/.ts
--main.ts
tasks
--build.js
--clean.js
--watch.js
--webserver.js
gulpfile.js
```

Hope this helps to find my issues.

Comment: Whats the exact issue some error or not working .. can provide more with image file of error or Code on plnkr which could hep to identify the issue

Comment: It's rendering. The Chrome DevTool doesn't show any errors, everthing seems to be working.

Comment: Sorry, ofc I meant it's NOT rendering.

Comment: Alrighty, I used the ROUTER_PROVIDERS from @angular/router-deprecated. As soon as I changed that to @angular/router, it worked just fine. That was my Edit-Issue. The first issue I had with the PanelMenu solved itself during my tryouts.. not sure what exactly solved that, but it's done. Thanks anyways. Maybe this will help other Newbes aswell :)